# Image distortion returns error: The tensor returned for Reshape_5:0 was not valid

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am attempting to add image distortion to my ConvNet model and am getting a really odd error. My data is in `TFRecords` format and I am using the `color_distorter()` function from the `CFIAR10` code. Below is some dummy code I threw together to see that everything was doing what I expected it to do. When I view the images after they are distorted there is no problem. The problem appears to arise after flattening the tensor or after it is run. For some reason, it will execute once, but the second time it throws an error. Below is my code and the error it returns. My current suspicion is that it might be the `tf.map_fn()` but I don't know.

```
def color_distorer(image, thread_id=0, scope=None):
    with tf.op_scope([image], scope, 'distort_color'):
        color_ordering = thread_id % 2

       if color_ordering == 0:
           image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=32. / 255.)
           image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
           image = tf.image.random_hue(image, max_delta=0.2)
           image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    elif color_ordering == 1:
           image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=32. / 255.)
           image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
           image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
           image = tf.image.random_hue(image, max_delta=0.2)

           # The random_* ops do not necessarily clamp.
        image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)
        return image

X_test_batch, y_test_batch = inputs(FLAGS.train_dir,
                                FLAGS.test_file,
                                FLAGS.batch_size,
                                FLAGS.n_epochs,
                                FLAGS.n_classes,
                                one_hot_labels=True,
                                imshape=160*160*3)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    # X = sess.run([X_test_batch])
    for i in range(5): #epochs
        image = tf.reshape(X_test_batch, [-1, 160, 160, 3])
        result = tf.map_fn(lambda img: color_distorer(img), image)
        X, y = sess.run([result, y_test_batch]) #to see what the distortion did
        for i in range(50): #all the images look distorted..
            if i%25 ==0:
                plt.title(y[i])
                plt.imshow(X[i])
                plt.show()
        print('******************') #This runs once... then breaks. Why?
        result = tf.reshape(result, [-1, 76800])
        dX, dy = sess.run([result, y_test_batch])
        print(dX)
```

Error:

```
******************
[[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
..., 
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]]
WARNING:tensorflow:tf.op_scope(values, name, default_name) is deprecated, use tf.name_scope(name, default_name, values)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The tensor returned for map_1/TensorArrayPack_1/TensorArrayGatherV2:0 was not valid.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/mcamp/Local SSHD/Python Projects/Garage Door   Project/FreshStart/ReadTFREcords.py", line 80, in <module>
  dX, dy = sess.run([result, y_test_batch])
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
 File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The tensor returned for map_1/TensorArrayPack_1/TensorArrayGatherV2:0 was not valid.
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in TensorFlow, can you give a self-contained example?

Comment: I had an epiphany and think I may understand what's going on but am still working through it.. and will post the code shortly..

Comment: I've got it running now but do every couple times I run it get the error again... so maybe it is a bug in Tensorflow also.. maybe the graph gets cached in memory or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I believe was happening was I resized `X_test_batch` back to the shape of an image. I then ran my distortion on it and called it `result`. It was this that I ran and viewed. After viewing, I resized it for the model back to being a flat image. During this, I change the names of some things calling it first `image` and then `result`. If the code just red from top to bottom I think it would have been fine but Tensorflow has the graph that it works from and so it was expecting result to be a 3d tensor when it got to the second iteration, but it was really a flat tensor that was trying to be put through `tf.map_fn`. `tf.map_fn` is something that resides on the graph and does not get executed until `sess.run()` and so this would be the cause of the error that I was seeing. I hope this makes sense and helps someone else down the road.

```
with tf.name_scope('TestingData'):
    X_test_batch, y_test_batch = inputs(FLAGS.train_dir,
                                       FLAGS.test_file,
                                       FLAGS.batch_size,
                                       FLAGS.n_epochs,
                                       FLAGS.n_classes,
                                       one_hot_labels=True,
                                       imshape=160*160*3)

image = tf.reshape(X_test_batch, [-1, 160, 160, 3])

image = tf.map_fn(lambda img: color_distorer(img), image)
with tf.Session() as sess:

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
     sess.run(init_op)
     coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
     threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
     # X = sess.run([X_test_batch])
     for i in range(5):
         # dX, dy = sess.run([result, y_test_batch])
         print('******************')
         image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 76800])
         dX, dy = sess.run([image, y_test_batch])
         distorted = np.reshape(dX, (-1, 160, 160, 3))
         print(dX.shape)
         print(distorted.shape)
         for i in range(50):
             if i%25 ==0:
                  print(distorted[i], dy[i])
                  plt.title(dy[i])
                  plt.imshow(distorted[i])
                  plt.show()
                  print(dX.shape)
```

Comment: `tf.reset_default_graph(); sess = tf.Session()` is your friend :)

Comment: it appears that if I stop training during a distortion point and attempt to start the model again it will throw the error. I have found a work around currently where I just comment out the `tf.map_fn` line run the model till it saves a checkpoint then run it again with the `tf.map_fn`.